# How to preinstall Chrome extension in Microsoft Chromium Edge?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, chromium

Microsoft Chromium Edge is the new web navigator of Microsoft. It shares the same Chromium base as Google Chrome. Thanks to that, it supports Google Chrome Extension.

But I cannot find how to automatically install Google Chrome extension at the same time as Edge installation. Any help ?

The context of my question is partial deployment in a big enterprise. I've searched in Microsoft documentation without success until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Edge (Chromium) browser is still in development stage and it is not officially launched yet.

The beta version of the browser is available for download which user can download from link below.

[Download MS Edge Chromium beta browser](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/)

**At present, it is not possible to preinstall the Chrome extensions in Edge chromium browser while installing the browser.**

If you want to install the Chrome extensions in Edge chromium browser than you can refer the link below.

[Install Chrome Extensions in Microsoft Edge Chromium](https://winaero.com/blog/install-chrome-extensions-in-microsoft-edge-chromium/)

I will take your requirement as a feature request for this browser and try to submit it via our internal channel.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.